# VBscript scheduled task error

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I have a VBScript that does a number of tasks, including moving files from one place to another.

Lots of copy/move/create folder/delete folder/delete files like this

```
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filesys.CopyFile "D:\Test Now\test.txt", "W:\test_2\test.txt"
```

I'm able to get the entire script to work when I run it manually by double clicking it and no errors come up. However, when I run it from scheduled task an error is shown "Path Not Found". I found this error by writing this error to a DB.

If

```
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
```

is off the script is stuck in that error. With it set to on, the script would skip the operations not carry out its function.

I've quadruple checked the paths to make sure its right. Is there something I should be aware of when running scripts with scheduled tasks?

Comment: What does it say when you type `dir "D:\Test Now\test.txt"` and `dir "W:\test_2\"` at the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are D:\ And W:\ local drives, or are they mapped network drives?  If they're mapped, the user running the process might not have those drives available.  Be sure you run the task as a privileged local account.  It's also best to log in to that account and run the command manually.  Once you verify that it works, then you can tighten up security if that's a concern.

Comment: Yes W:\ is a mapped drive and I have rights to that drive. I have rights to that drive and I am able to do get it to work when I run it manually instead of a scheduled task. Could there be other caveats regarding rights on scheduled tasks?

Comment: running the command manually works, however it seems that the problem is I have to be logged into the account that the scheduled tasks runs from, even if my account have the rights to make changes on the drives

Answer (score 0):

This jumps to mind: enclose your paths in quotes `"`. One of the two has a space in it. And VBSscript certainly won't like that.

```
filesys.CopyFile "D:\Test Now\test.txt", "W:\test_2\test.txt"
```

Yup, just tested it, and that is indeed what was causing the error.

By the way, you may know this, but unless you want to enter a debugging nightmare, you shouldn't use `On Error Resume Next` unless you have a very specific reason to do so .

Comment: ahhhh I forgot to input the quotes in my question, I did in the script, stupid mistake! updated the question to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

An old topic I know, but this may help someone:

My scheduled task was running under a specific user. Using the component services snap in for MMC I needed to give the user 'Launch and activation' permissions. Once this was done, the scheduled task ran correctly.